# How to use "iHarder" base 64 encoder on android

Tags: java, android, base64

This is the Base64 class :

```
http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/
```

the problem is, i have two `Editext` and one `Button` in my activity.so i need to use this for encode the string from `Edittext1` with the one Button and then it show us the result(encoded result) on `EditText2`.

how we can do this and use this class for encode the strings?

i read the details about this class and i cannot figure out how can i use this for encode (input - output string in android)

How we can do this ?

Cheers!.

Comment: What did you try and what specific problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a third-party class in this case - Android already has a [`Base64` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html).

Just use `Base64.encodeToString(byte[], int)` and `Base64.decode(String, int)`.

Note that base64-encoding is for *binary* data, so if your actual source is text, you'll need to work out an encoding to use first... e.g. UTF-8. For example:

```
String sourceText = ...;
byte[] sourceBinary = sourceText.getByte(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String base64 = Base64.encode(sourceBinary, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: hei jon, thank you.is there any way for encode an string to base64 with message digest? like this example with try-catch:[http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_simple_class_to_compute_md5_hash.xml](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_simple_class_to_compute_md5_hash.xml) i can do this on android i iknow how to encode an string with this sample on MD5 but Base64 no.

Comment: @androidprogrammer: It's not at all clear what you mean by "encode an string to base64 with message digest". Both message digests *and* base64 take binary data as input, not strings. So first you'd need to encode the string as binary data, e.g. using UTF-8 (not ISO-8859-1 as per the linked example, unless you're fond of losing data...)

Comment: So, i'm trying to learn this goddamn java :d thank you.

Comment: @androidprogrammer: None of that is really Java-specific - it's about the nature of text data, binary data, what it means to encode binary data as base64, and what it means to take a message digest...

Comment: You're right.actually, i need to read more about the java for use it on code.with the best wishes.

Comment: @androidprogrammer: No, I think the first thing you should do is make sure you understand your *actual* requirements, which seem pretty vague. The Java part will be easy once you've understood the domain.

Comment: finally, i found this on onClick : `http://paste.ubuntu.com/11154373/` simple and powerfull.thank you jon.